# Swagger documentation for Kafka Listener

Tags: spring, swagger, swagger-ui, spring-kafka

I have used Swagger to generate a document for rest API, but I am building Kafka listener and wanted to generate a document for it. Do we have any possibility using Swagger or something similar?

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to document? A REST API is something that you might want to publish for external users to use. A Kafka listener does not hava a public API, it's just an internal implementation that receives records from Kafka.

Comment: Interesting question. Messaging (via JMS with ActiveMQ) is the main way of communication between our services. We document all our listeners manually which is a great pain. I would love to have a "Swagger for messaging".

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, our core domain layer is sending a different specialized message to the different topic, and this becomes a contract for another service, of what they are going to receive it.

Comment: I am not sure it's entirely relevant to your requirements, but you might find [Spring Cloud Contract](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/) interesting.

Comment: thanks @GaryRussell I will have a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same need, and decided to create something myself.
I call it swagger4kafka, and it works very similar to swagger, but it documents `@KafkaListener` annotated methods instead of `RestController` methods.

Its source is hosted in github: [swagger4kafka repository](https://github.com/stavshamir/springwolf)
In the readme section you can find how to use it.

I would not say it is production ready yet, but I think it can be quite useful for internal use.

*Note:*
'swagger4kafka' is now called '**Springwolf**' (and also support RabbitMQ)

Answer (score 1):

Stav Shamir has actually created an improved open source solution called **Springwolf**.

It does auto-detect the KafkaListener annotations and creates AsyncAPI compliant documentation for the asynchronous world (i.e. Kafka) - just like Swagger does for synchronous REST APIs.